# Install Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, graphics-card, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best answer for: “my Internet is not working”?](https://superuser.com/questions/117317/what-is-the-best-answer-for-my-internet-is-not-working)

My video is not working properly, I don't have the right resolution to choose and I lost visual effects.

Here are the details:
Ubuntu 11.10 - 32 bit
Acer Aspire 4736Z

```
daniel@gerep:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display:0 UNCLAIMED   
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5110(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3400000-d34fffff
```

How do I install the video driver?

Ubuntu installed: `VESA: Intel(r)Cantiga Graphics` but I loose some of my resolution options

Comment: some additional info would be good, since when does this occur, what did you change, what was the status before?

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu and the Video was "Unknown" but when I made the updates, the required ones, the video was gone, now I only have this VESA that is not working properly. I have tried so many things on Ask Ubuntu but no solution

Comment: - http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/chpsts/4m/

- http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+controllers&ProductProduct=Mobile+Intel%C2%AE+4+Series+Express+Chipset+Family&OSVersion=Linux*

Comment: I just downloaded the file, gonna try

Comment: I'm downloading the Intel file...lets see what happens, I'll report back

Comment: I made the download but it came with two PDF and a .exe file

Comment: I have made the download twice and same result..a damn exe file